# How to find the starting and ending address of Stack memory for a program?

Tags: c

Any one can explain how to find the stack starting address and ending address through programming

Comment: With the tag C, this doesn't make sense. C knows nothing about a "*stack*"

Comment: This question is utterly meaningless. There is no stack in the C standard. This might be more meaningful if a platform was mentioned: the computer architecture and the operating system. But even then - on those computers that use stacks, the stack can have the bottom of the stack but no limit for the top; and a program can have multiple threads of execution each with their own stacks, etc.

Comment: check it in map file

Comment: And then, I can't think of a good reason you would need this -- care to explain? There *might* be a much better approach to address your *original* problem.

Comment: Write a recursive function that prints the address of a local variable. Until it breaks.

Comment: For added confusion, a 'program' may have more than one stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way of getting the stack base and the limit in C simply because C doesn't understand call stacks.

We can talk about a particular implementation that uses a stack for calling though.

Now each implementation uses some kind of a Thread Local Storage pointed by one of the registers. On X86 they use one of the unused segment registers. 
These implementations also provide a way of accessing this TLB.

If you are on windows you can look at [NtCurrentTEB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh285210(v=vs.85).aspx).

And the [TEB Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block). You can see the field - StackBase and StackLimit.

A code for getting the stack base and limit in C (similar can be written in CPP) (On Windows only) will be

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>

struct _TEB {
        NT_TIB NtTib;
};

void *getStackBase(){
        return NtCurrentTeb()->NtTib.StackBase;
}
void *getStackLimit(){
        return NtCurrentTeb()->NtTib.StackLimit;
}
```